# How do I use the Simple HTML DOM Parser in plugin when other plugin already uses it?

Tags: php, plugin-development, include, library

In a plugin I am currently coding, I want to use the Simple HTML DOM Parser library. However, when I include it

```
require(CPS_PLUGIN_PATH . '/vendor/simple_html_dom.php');
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_get_html() (previously declared in /www/htdocs/12345/mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/custom-post-snippets/vendor/simple_html_dom.php:48) in /www/htdocs/12345/mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/fast-velocity-minify/libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php on line 54
```

So obviously the Fast Velocity Minify plugin is already using it. What do I do here, if I don't want to mess around in the library itself? What's the best practice in a case like this?

Comment: `if ( ! function_exists( 'file_get_html' ) ) { load the library }` or try `require_once` instead of `require`. But that's a generic PHP matter.

Comment: I just tried it with function_exists, however, the other plugin seems to be loaded after mine and the error is occuring in that other plugin. So I'm trying to adjust the order in which the plugins are loaded now. Still working on it.

Comment: when/where are you loading it? Have you tried waiting until you need to use it to load it instead? Or using the built in DOM parsing API in PHP?

Comment: @TheKidsWantDjent sorry for the late reply, but I actually thought that you were just trying to load the library right before you *use it* and not when WordPress loads your plugin. So if it's the latter, then you could check how the other plugin loads the library, e.g. what hook the plugin uses, and then use the same hook (with a lower number as the priority which means a higher priority) or an earlier hook to ensure the library in your plugin is loaded first. However, I'd probably only load (`require_once`) the library when I need to actually use it, just as Tom pointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with plugin load order, you can trigger the `require` part a bit later, e.g. via the [`plugins_loaded` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/).

```
function csp_require_simplehtml() {
    if (!function_exists('file_get_html')) {
        require(CPS_PLUGIN_PATH . '/vendor/simple_html_dom.php');
    }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'csp_require_simplehtml');
```

Comment: Your solution is way more elegant than mine! It works! Nice!

Comment: To be totally safe, you might even use `after_setup_theme` (after all, a theme might ship the library as well ...). See [resources like this](https://rachievee.com/the-wordpress-hooks-firing-sequence/) for a list in order of the hooks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sally CJ pointed out I had to use `function_exists('file_get_html')`, like so:

```
if (!function_exists('file_get_html')) {
    require(CPS_PLUGIN_PATH . '/vendor/simple_html_dom.php');
}
```

However, that did still not do the trick at first, since the error was not occuring in my plugin but in the Fast Velocity Minify plugin, that was loaded first. So I had to change the order in which the plugins where loaded. I put my plugin at the very end of the loading sequence, with this code:

```
function csp_load_last()
{
    $path = str_replace( WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/', '', __FILE__ );
    if ( $plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) {
        if ( $key = array_search( $path, $plugins ) ) {
            array_splice( $plugins, $key, 1 );
            array_push( $plugins, $path );
            update_option( 'active_plugins', $plugins );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'activated_plugin', 'csp_load_last' );
```

The code has to go into the main plugin file, which in my case is the `custom-post-snippets.php`.

I only hope this doesn't cause any other errors, but until now it seems to be working fine like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't face this issue when installing the Simple HTML DOM Parser [library](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/index.html) with php [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), as it creates an [autoloader](https://opensource.com/article/23/4/autoloading-namespaces-php) for the given library,

```php
require_once plugin_dir_path( __DIR__ ) . 'assets/simple-html-dom/autoload.php';

$dom = HtmlDomParser::str_get_html( $html_raw );
```

and loads the required classes in the library's defined namespace, so as to avoid any conflict with similar named classes.  If the class is already loaded, it doesn't try to load it again.

`composer` creates a unique autoloader class for this project/plugin,

```php
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit878f98a67b3b98dbca236a0ccf2fa53e::getLoader();
```

so there is no possiblity of it classhing with another autoloader either.

Neat!